# Fill substrate gap before flooring tile

Tags: flooring, plywood

I plan to set commercial flooring tile in a closet (so the aesthetics are secondary) and have 1/2" plywood over 3/4" OSB for substrate. Now, as you can see in the picture, the plywood wasn't perfectly cut to retrofit the somewhat irregular shape of the closet and has gaps about as wide as a carpenter pencil at the widest.

[[ Picture pending ]]

Should I try to fill the gaps with something like a square dowel + wood glue + wood filler or will it be fine to leave it like this. I don't expect anyone to be walking around these edges in the closet so I don't anticipate heavy load exposure.

Answer (score 2):

If the areas are not going to be stepped on, go on over it, it will only be a bit of thinset going in there, and the tile will span it with no issues.

Comment: I would agree a pencil width wound not be a problem when setting the tiles fill the crack with some thinset and then it won't matter if it is being walked on or not.+